# how to enable checksum value in hdfs?

Tags: azure, hadoop, hdfs, azure-hdinsight

How to enable checksum value in hdfs.

Using hadoop (Hadoop 2.7.3) on the top of hdinsight cluster in azure.

I tred to check checksum value using this command:-

```
 hadoop fs -checksum <path-to-hdfs>/filename.txt
```

then checksum value is coming as NONE.

Read  [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html) that "the usual checksum is “NONE” .

so my issue is how to enable checksum value?

Comment: What is the protocol of `<path-to-hdfs>` you used? `hdfs` or `wasb`? If using `hdfs` now, please try to use `wasb` or `wasbs` instead of it, and see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage to know details about HDFS on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to command for HDFS on Azure HDInsight.

```
hadoop fs -checksum wasbs://containername@xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/folder/filename.txt
```